# How to use return command instead of printf to get the same output of a defined float function?

Tags: c, function

Can I use a **return** command instead of **printf** in the **tables1** function, and still get the same output as it is giving me currently?
The **tables1** function is defined at the starting of the following code which presently executes without warnings or errors:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

float tables1(float a,float b)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        printf(" %.2f\n", a*i);
        printf(" %.2f\n ", b*i);
    }
    printf(" if all tasks not executed plz check the code \n");
    printf("just to check how the computer treated your number input as, lets print it again\n %.2f \n", a);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    float a,b;
    printf("enter the numbers whose first 10 multiples u want to see\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("following below are the multiples \n\n ");

    tables1(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output image is attached.

Also, when i wrote the above code initially, i did not write any return statement in the **tables1** function definition, hence i got a warning during build, so just to see if it works, i wrote a **return 0;** compiled it, and the warning was gone yet, leaving me in dissatisfaction from a second query which is:- 
Doesnt the float function have a different kind of **return** statement, or is **return 0** rightly used?
i feel there may be couple of such instances(like mistakes) in my program that may have gone unnoticed by me.

[image: Output of the code i have written above]

Comment: please explain why you want to do this.

Comment: if you make tables1 a void function it doesn't need to return anything

Comment: because the reference materials i use, have a lot of simpler examples of int functions which use a return inside their definition to give outputs.......these are simple examples like  ' return a+1; }' and it gives the output fine. But i couldnt come accross a float example of such type not even in some normal search i did on the net

Comment: I think you need to reiterate over your understanding of functions (or "procedures") in general programming...

Comment: To answer your first question (literally): no. The `printf` *does* something visible, `return a;` does not. It's also a nonsensical return value: it's the same `a` that you fed the function with, and it doesn't get modified.

Comment: hey @Jongware thanks for that, just i believe there may be a misprint on the page that i was using to go through some simple examples of the functions where they have used a "return" statement to get outputs like i described in my earlier comments.

Comment: in that case is there a way to find out what is wrong with my grasping on this (i am learning C again after a long time) as in, even if the code is right or running right, are there any wrong syntax habbits that i have developed in the context of this code. Or am i getting too over-worried uselessly.

Comment: @SteveO'Connor yes i tried doing void, yes it works perfectly as u said, dint have to return anything, well that is a good alter solution, just that i wanted to concentrate on float type more extensively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the return value of `tables` anywhere. Furthermore, `tables` already takes a `float` as input, hence you cannot really check inside `tables` whether that number matches the user's input, since the input (a string) is unknown to `tables`.

You might as well change the function to `void tables` and not return any value. The part of the code that deals with the user's input is in `main`, and there is no need to pass such details onto a function dealing with `float`s.

Meanwhile `scanf` *does* return a value which you are also ignoring – do check the documentation of each library function you are using, and determine whether the return value might be useful... (There are also other functions to parse numbers from strings, e.g., `strtod`.)

Comment: yes i tried doing void, yes it works perfectly as u said, dint have to return anything, well that is a good alter solution, just that i wanted to concentrate on float type more extensively hence i wanted to know explicitly what should a float function return, which is not described properly anywhere that i tried to search, or atleast not in simple terms.

Comment: re. “what should a float function return“, depends entirely on the function. If you're using it only for its side-effects, such as printing tables, perhaps it should return nothing, or it can return a value to indicate success/failure. If it is a “true” function used to compute a value (e.g., the square root function), it should obviously return that value…

Comment: so i believe that means, "return 0;" would work for both int and float type functions, coz not returning anything for a float function is an obvious error/warning. Well this helped me know more, thanks.

Comment: A function that always returns 0 is quite pointless, and returning nothing (i.e., having a `void` function) is _not_ an indication of error/warning, quite the opposite.

Comment: yes yes i get it, just that i meant not returnig anything in a float type function was giving me warnings coz it was not a void function but a float function......newz u got the point and i got what u said.....i guess most of my work would require only int and void type functions and may be one or two others (while i am learning C programming).